# Trying to implement an exponential averaging circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

With basis in this:

[image]

If i wanted an exponential averaging circuit with time constant t = 35ms i would just use this equation : t = RC where i can choose one value for R and compute C.

What i dont understand is how does this simple circuit makes an average?

Comment: Lowpass sounds so much more to the point than the PR-like "exponential average".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A time average of a signal is a definite integral of the signal vs. time, divided by some time constant.

All we need to show is that the voltage on the capacitor provides such a time integral.

The RC circuit's behavior is described by the differential equation

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{dU_o}{dt} &= {1\over C} I_C(t) \\
&= {1\over C} I_R(t) \\
&= {1\over C} \frac{U_i(t)-U_o(t)}{R} \\
&= {1 \over RC} \left[ U_i(t)-U_o(t) \right]. \\
\end{aligned}
$$

We can rearrange this into a standard linear form for a 1st degree ODE:

$$
U_o^{'}(t) + {1\over RC}\cdot U_o(t) = {1 \over RC} U_i(t).
$$

The solution is

$$
\mu\, U_o(t)={1\over RC}\int{\mu\, U_i(\tau)\, d\tau},
$$

where the integrating factor

$$
\mu = e^{\int{1/(RC)\, dt}} = e^{T/(RC)}
$$

is a constant, and \$T=t-t_0\$ is the interval of integration.

Since the integrating factor is a constant, the solution simplifies to

$$
U_o(t) = {1 \over RC}\int_{t_0}^{t}{U_i(\tau) d\tau}.
$$

It is a time average of the input voltage, normalized by the reciprocal time constant \${1\over RC}\$.

There is a [handy cheatsheet for differential equations](https://ncc.metu.edu.tr/sites/default/files/ODE-Review.pdf).

Comment: Why in the figure it says it is an exponential averaging?

Comment: @G0tBlackOps I'm not sure. The text you're citing is written in an unnecessarily convoluted way, and doesn't seem to use common terminology.