# Trying to implement an averaging circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

[Based in one of the answers given to me](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/629252/trying-to-implement-an-exponential-averaging-circuit)

I made the input signal be a sine with a 1V offset and 1 V amplitude.

[image]

If I were to apply the equation given from the user that answered what would the interval of integration be in this case?

Edit:

One of the answers from the linked post:

The RC circuit's behavior is described by the differential equation

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{dU_o}{dt} &= {1\over C} I_C(t) \\
&= {1\over C} I_R(t) \\
&= {1\over C} \frac{U_i(t)-U_o(t)}{R} \\
&= {1 \over RC} \left[ U_i(t)-U_o(t) \right]. \\
\end{aligned}
$$

We can rearrange this into a standard linear form for a 1st degree ODE:

$$
U_o^{'}(t) + {1\over RC}\cdot U_o(t) = {1 \over RC} U_i(t).
$$

The solution is

$$
\mu\, U_o(t)={1\over RC}\int{\mu\, U_i(\tau)\, d\tau},
$$

where the integrating factor

$$
\mu = e^{\int{1/(RC)\, dt}} = e^{T/(RC)}
$$

is a constant, and \$T=t-t_0\$ is the interval of integration.

Since the integrating factor is a constant, the solution simplifies to

$$
U_o(t) = {1 \over RC}\int_{t_0}^{t}{U_i(\tau) d\tau}.
$$

It is a time average of the input voltage, normalized by the reciprocal time constant \${1\over RC}\$.

Edit2:

So solving the integral for the circuit i posted above for 5 ms:

$$
U_o(5m) = {1 \over RC}\int_{0}^{5m}{1+ sin(2*\pi*1000\tau) d\tau} = 1.8 .
$$

I should get a value around 0.98 and not 1.8 if i look at the plot.

I think i'm missing something simple

Comment: What is good enough in averaging? Is it for one specific frequency?

Comment: Frequencies around 1kHz-20kHz. I'm just trying to related the U0(t) equation to this circuit

Comment: What you have in that circuit is a low pass filter. That is not "averaging"